# Is there a way to combine node modues with similar functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When you work with node.js, it comes the point where you have module-dependencies with more or less similar functions in it, like underscore, lodash and lazy. (maybe in different versions)

Is there a opportunity to define which module from a similar method-bundle has to be used so that a preprocessor can replace all matched functions in code?

Comment: I hope there is not. This this the benefit of dependencies management. Use différent module at different point

Comment: yes, but what if one or more modules use some slower librarys for the same task you know a better one? not every usefull framework is well updated this times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want that, but what you could do is something like this:

Create a file containing a single require for the module you decided to use now, for example `underscore`, let's call this file wrapper.js.

```
module.exports = require('underscore')
```

Wherever you would normally do `require('underscore')`, you now use `require('./path/to/wrapper.js'). If you decide you want`lodash`now, just replace the require in`wrapper.js`.

Maybe this is not really what you're asking: If you want some preprocessor doing this automatically, you could in theory write something doing that, but I doubt you'll have benefit from it: Debugging subtle changes between the libraries which you code turns out to depend on might negate any gain.